# Wrong tokenization of Japanese verbs using SQLite FTS ICU tokenizer

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, full-text-search, tokenize, cjk

I'm trying to use SQLite FTS ICU tokenizer for Japanese on an Android device.

Here is my query:

`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tokenizer_ja USING fts3tokenize(icu, ja);`

`SELECT token, position, start, end FROM tokenizer_ja WHERE input=?;`

`?` is replaced by the phrase I want to tokenize.

It's almost working, but there is a problem with verbs. For example, the sentence `日本語で話します` is tokenized as `日本語`, `で`, `話`, `し`, `ます`.

`話します` is one word and should be one token.

I tried different verbs and there is the same problem with all verbs. Only the dictionary form tokenization is correct.

Is there a way to have a good tokenization? A tokenizer option that can be activated? Any explanation why the tokenization is like that?

Comment: Why don't you tokenize by chars? Some regex like `\P{M}\p{M}*+` would do to match a code point.

Comment: Pretty sure that's perfectly correct, what make you so sure it "should" be one token? `話, し, ます` is the decomposition of 話 + 連用形 for する + formal present tense conjugation ます. Run this through MeCab or something and you'd get the same thing (although you'd get the POS tags so you could tell what just happened)?

Comment: 話します is a conjugation of 話す, so I expected to have it as one word. MeCab separates `話し` and `ます`, but keeps `話` and `し` together, and it separates `日本` and `語`. http://www.edrdg.org/~jwb/cgi-bin/mecabdisp?sent=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7%E8%A9%B1%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99

Comment: Reading through the Sqlite3 docs, they're just using http://site.icu-project.org/ to do the tokenization, so if the default build doesn't expose that in the way you need, you might need to post to https://sqlite.org/forum/forum rather than here if you want an authoritative answer in a speedy fashion =/